# How to obtain container managed entity manager in JavaEE 6 without using annotations

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, java-ee-6

How to obtain container managed entity manager in JavaEE 6 without using annotations

Comment: In addition to my answer, let me ask you a quesion: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a legacy JavaEE application (ear with one WAR and one EJB) which I can extend *only* by adding JARs to the lib folder. It seems that it is not possible to obtain an entity manager in a library (even if the persistence.xml is also defined in a lib-JAR). Furthermore I seems to make a huge difference whether the control flow is initiated by the web container (user request) or by a ejb container (e.g. timer). I fear that it is not possible to obtain an entity manager when processing a web request, all attempts using `@PersistenceContext` and `@PersistenceUnit` yielded null...

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get the entity manager using JNDI as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm#CIHFIDHI

Additionally have a look at section 7.2 ("Obtaining an EntityManager") of the [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which works on Glassfish 3.1 (thanks to Thomas for the links):

```
@Stateless
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit", name="persistence/myUnit")
public class MyLibraryService {

   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public String getFirstName(String userId) {
     EntityManager em = (EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/myUnit");

     TypedQuery<String> tq = em.createQuery("select fn from Person p where p.id = :userId", String.class);
     tq.setParameter("userId", userId);
     ...
   }

}
```

where `myUnit` is the unit name defined in `persistence.xml`.

`MyLibraryService` can simply be injected into other classes:

```
@Inject
private MyLibraryService myLibraryService;
```